# How to find and group all same value of a specific field from a mysql database by using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sorting, group-by

I have a database table named `'member'`. From `member` table I would like to group all same `'tin'` member in an arranged manner.

Suppose To signup in my website `'tin'` is a mandatory field. One `'tin'` can be used for multiple accounts.

Now I have 1000 member who has already signed up in my website using same tin number. I would like to view all same tin member only not all member. And I must have to group them together and sort them by tin in Ascending order.

Note: In database `'tin'` field is `varchar`. 
Some tin number are given to understand in which manner it is inserted in database:

```
159759767359
115172244423
360783365646
116363519966
159759767359
115172244423
```

I don't have any problem about viewing the array result and table.
To be specific my problem is only about database query.

This is my controller

```
$data['sametinmember'] = $this->voter_mod->sametinmember();
$this->load->view('voter/sametinmember',$data);
```

I tried this way in my Model but no luck.

```
    $sql = 'select tin, count(*) as Count from member group by tin   having count(*) > 1';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    $arr = $query->result_array();      
    return $arr;
```

Please help me to find exact solution I have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should use  a subselect and a in clause

```
    'select * from member where tin in (
        select tin
        from member 
        having count(*) > 1
        group by tin)
     '
```